# How to Add multi field input with php query handling data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a working add multi field select option field that can get data from db and display in select option. However when I need to add more select option input below with php handling data

I dont know how to put the php and sql inside the script tag, or is that any jquery plugin can handle the php data

Here is working select option

```
<table id="worked">
<th>Item Name</th>
<th><button  class="add-row">  + </button>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="item_name[]" >
<?php 

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM stock");

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
?>                                
<option> <?php echo $row['name']?> </option>

<?php
}
?>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the problem script function, it work fine if use select input without php

```
$('#worked .add-row').click(function () {

var template = '<tr><td>
<select name="item_name[]" >
<?php 

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM stock");

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
?>                                
<option> <?php echo $row['name']?> </option>

<?php
}
?>
</select>
</td></tr>';

$('#worked tbody').append(template);
});
```

Comment: Having PHP inside your HTML inside JavaScript inside your PHP is not a sustainable development model. Why not emit that data as clean JSON values and manipulate the HTML using a client-side template like Handlebars or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `}`

**Change your code from this:**

```
<?php 

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM stock");

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
?>                                
<option> <?php echo $row['name']?> </option>

<?php
}
?>
```

**With this:**

```
<?php result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM stock"); ?>

<?php if ($result->num_rows > 0):?>
<?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):?>                                
<option> <?php echo $row['name']; ?> </option>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif;?>
```